# Disable tab shortcuts with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I have a content editable div and whenever I press tab, it selects a thing on the left (I’m using edge, probably isn’t same on other browsers) and preventDefault() isn’t helping. How can I do this?

```
window.addEventListener(‘key down’, event => {
  switch (event.key){
    case ‘tab’:
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
  }
});
```

doesn’t work…

Answer (score 1):

- it's `keydown` not `key down`
- you can't use `‘` as a quote in JavaScript
- it's `Tab` not `tab`

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
  switch (event.key){
    case 'Tab':
      event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```